# Using rxjs and ngrx store to deal with fragile API

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngrx-store

Using Angular 6 with RxJS 5, ngx-restangular and ngrx store.

I'm dealing with an API that breaks very easily, and can easily take 5+ seconds to respond, or frequently responds with 500.

I need to send in multiple (n) requests, I've been using forkJoin but I'd like to start populating the UI as soon as the anything is returned, and not have to wait for all to return at once (and also if one of those calls fails, the rest will continue so I can at least display that data).  I also tried combineLatest, but that one also waits for all of the observables to emit something.

I think there's something wrong with the way I have it set up in ngrx store and could use some advice on how to accomplish this.

Say I have this in my services to accept an array of timestamps:

```
getForTimestamps(timestamps: string[] = []) {
    const observableBatch = [];

    timestamps.forEach((timestamp) => {
      observableBatch.push(this.restangular.all('myapi').customGET('', {timestamp})
        .pipe(
          catchError((err) => observableThrowError(err) ),
          map((r) => {
            return {[timestamp]: r}
          })));
    })
    return observableBatch.length > 0 ? observableForkJoin(observableBatch) : observableOf([]);
}
```

However, this doesn't emit anything to my effect until all of those observables have completed.  Should I pull out the array observable and deal with the array in the effect instead?

I apologize if this has been asked before, I couldn't figure out what to search for.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: cant you just use merge?

Comment: When I try that I get a problem for some reason within ngrx (I assume it's something within the effect): TypeError ""active" is read-only" but it actually locks up my browser when it happens making it tough to debug.  I think that would do what I'm looking for so I'll keep at it.

Comment: this may actually be a use case for mergeScan which i've never found a use for before